# Alter Jquery table script to only filter one column and not all columns

Tags: jquery, filter, datatables

I am using the jquery script called datatables http://datatables.net/ to display some data being pulled from my database. I have modded the example shown here for my own table
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html
. The problem I am having now is it is placing a filter on every single column, is there a way I can mod this so that there is only a filter on the column of my table name Reps ?. If there is do I need to apply a class to this column called 'Reps' or can I use the column header / footer to specify to only filter that particular column ?.

```
    (function($) {
    /*
     * Function: fnGetColumnData
     * Purpose:  Return an array of table values from a particular column.
     * Returns:  array string: 1d data array
     * Inputs:   object:oSettings - dataTable settings object. This is always the last argument past to the function
     *           int:iColumn - the id of the column to extract the data from
     *           bool:bUnique - optional - if set to false duplicated values are not filtered out
     *           bool:bFiltered - optional - if set to false all the table data is used (not only the filtered)
     *           bool:bIgnoreEmpty - optional - if set to false empty values are not filtered from the result array
     * Author:   Benedikt Forchhammer <b.forchhammer /AT\ mind2.de>
     */
    $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnGetColumnData = function ( oSettings, iColumn, bUnique, bFiltered, bIgnoreEmpty ) {
        // check that we have a column id
        if ( typeof iColumn == "undefined" ) return new Array();

        // by default we only wany unique data
        if ( typeof bUnique == "undefined" ) bUnique = true;

        // by default we do want to only look at filtered data
        if ( typeof bFiltered == "undefined" ) bFiltered = true;

        // by default we do not wany to include empty values
        if ( typeof bIgnoreEmpty == "undefined" ) bIgnoreEmpty = true;

        // list of rows which we're going to loop through
        var aiRows;

        // use only filtered rows
        if (bFiltered == true) aiRows = oSettings.aiDisplay;
        // use all rows
        else aiRows = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster; // all row numbers

        // set up data array   
        var asResultData = new Array();

        for (var i=0,c=aiRows.length; i<c; i++) {
            iRow = aiRows[i];
            var aData = this.fnGetData(iRow);
            var sValue = aData[iColumn];

            // ignore empty values?
            if (bIgnoreEmpty == true && sValue.length == 0) continue;

            // ignore unique values?
            else if (bUnique == true && jQuery.inArray(sValue, asResultData) > -1) continue;

            // else push the value onto the result data array
            else asResultData.push(sValue);
        }

        return asResultData;
    }}(jQuery));


    function fnCreateSelect( aData )
    {
        var r='<select><option value=""></option>', i, iLen=aData.length;
        for ( i=0 ; i<iLen ; i++ )
        {
            r += '<option value="'+aData[i]+'">'+aData[i]+'</option>';
        }
        return r+'</select>';
    }


    $(document).ready(function() {
        /* Initialise the DataTable */
        var oTable = $('#dashboard').dataTable( {
          "bJQueryUI": true,

            "bInfo": true,

            "bAutoWidth": true,

            "bFilter": true,

            "bLengthChange": true,

            "bPaginate": true,

            "bProcessing": true,

             "bSort": true,

              "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

               "aaSorting": [[ 9, "desc" ]],

                "iDisplayLength": 5,

                "bLengthChange": false   
        } );

        /* Add a select menu for each TH element in the table footer */
        $("tfoot th").each( function ( i ) {
            this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect( oTable.fnGetColumnData(i) );
            $('select', this).change( function () {
                oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i );
            } );
        } );
    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eq()` method to select a element at particular index. It reduces the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

E.g. If you want to select second column from the table you can do this.

```
$('table thead th').eq(1);
```

You can use a pseudo selector also to select the element at a specified index.

```
$('table thead th:eq(1)');
```

References:
`eq()`  - http://api.jquery.com/eq/
`:eq()` - http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: Thanks :-)   , is that on this line ? /* Add a select menu for each TH element in the table footer */
   $("tfoot th").each( function ( i ) {

Comment: Which column do you want to select from the footer?